Ms Teams Deep link to autologin Webex Calling
I'm trying to create a deep link to programmatically click on the continue button within the Webex calling app inside of Teams. Currently it requires the end user to click and if the user doesn't it breaks functionality of the calling system we are using.
Picture of the button I am trying to automate
Teams Document where I found entity call
How I setup Developer Mode for teams
What I have so far: Entered into CMD - Which will launch the app within teams so I know this works.
start msteams:/l/entity/0924e969-85d8-4acb-8687-faacd6abd228

I believe the AppID and EntityID are the same but not sure.
With Developer mode Enabled:
I can see the element for the button is close1:
Teams Element Explorer
Within the console I can see the info Authentication#initWebex() When I click the continue button and it logs in for the user.
With Fiddler I can see teams reaching out to msteams-calling.webex.com
So following MS documentation I would expect the full call to be like:
start msteams:/l/entity/0924e969-85d8-4acb-8687-faacd6abd228/0924e969-85d8-4acb-8687-faacd6abd228?webUrl=https://msteams-calling.webex.com&close1

start msteams:/l/entity/0924e969-85d8-4acb-8687-faacd6abd228/0924e969-85d8-4acb-8687-faacd6abd228?webUrl=https://msteams-calling.webex.com&Authentication#initWebex()

Which they don't work so I know I am not understanding the Webex app or MS documentation correctly.
I feel like my only next step is to get the teams SDK and run some JS queries against it but I feel like I'm a little out of my element trying that. Just hoping someone with some better experience with this can point me in the right direction.
Thanks for any help!!
10/21 Update:
I think I figured out the entity ID now
start msteams:/l/entity/0924e969-85d8-4acb-8687-faacd6abd228/CISCO_EXTENSION_FIRST

Now I just need to figured out the URL is I think.

There are formatting tools available. Please [Edit] your question to include  code boxes for your code, replace the element button image with the actual text in another code box, and tidy up the Teams Doc: link so that it appears more like your DeveloperMode: link.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you please provide more details on your issue? From the description it is not quite clear. FYI, Deep links in Microsoft Teams allow you to navigate directly to a specific part of an app. The format for a deep link is typically: msteams:/l/entity/{appId}/{entityId}?webUrl={webUrl} Where: appId is the ID of your app, entityId is the ID of the specific entity within the app, webUrl is the URL that the deep link should open.

@Prasad-MSFT I added a screenshot of the button I want to automate. This is a 3rd party application that I didn't create, I just want to automate the auth so that it isn't missed by end users.

@DerekHartman, so basically you want to autologin using deep link format without clicking on 'Continue' button?

@Prasad-MSFT Exactly what I am trying to do.

Sorry, but the feature you want to implement doesn't seem to be feasible. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams Feedback Portal.
